# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in 'page URL'

Tags: php

```
<?php
    namespace security;
    class Pbkdf2
    {
        const HASH_ITERATIONS   = 6000;
        const SALT_ITERATIONS   = 10;
        const POMPOUS_SECRET    = <<<TOKEN
    vT@sw6b7,GD#orY8iQG%CbHLyzeziWFNWGnew=X]QuFfUtc(vP
    TOKEN;

        public static function generateRandomSalt($iterationCount = Pbkdf2::SALT_ITERATIONS)
        {
            if ($iterationCount < 10)
            {
                $iterationCount = 10;
            }
            $rand   = array();
            for ($i = 0; $i < $iterationCount; ++$i) {
                $rand[] = rand(0, 2147483647);
            }
            return strtolower(hash('sha256', implode('', $rand)));
        }

        public static function checklogin($password, $hash, $salt, $iterationCount = Pbkdf2::HASH_ITERATIONS)
        {
            $hashExpected   = self::hash($password, $salt, $iterationCount);
            return $hashExpected === $hash;
        }

        public static function hash($password, $salt, $iterationCount = Pbkdf2::HASH_ITERATIONS, $secret = Pbkdf2::POMPOUS_SECRET)
        {
            $hash   = $password;
            for ($i = 0; $i < $iterationCount; ++$i)
            {
                $hash   = strtolower(hash('sha256', $secret . $hash . $salt));
            }
            return $hash;
        }
    }

?>
```

This is the code from a PHP page loaded in to another page using AJAX. This throws the error

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in 'page url' on line 2** .

The sad fact is that I am not getting this error in localhost. I am seeing this error only in the server.

What is the hidden fact behind this?

Comment: This is a syntax error and has nothing to do with the URL of the page. You're most likely looking at a misplaced string somewhere. What line does it say it's on and what is on that line?

Comment: Which version of PHP is running on your server? Which version is on localhost?

Comment: h2ooooooo and deceze: Updated the question. It is on line 2.

Comment: @andrewsi: The version is 5.2.17 in the server and 5.3.8 in the local.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your server runs an old PHP version which does not support namespaces yet.

Comment: The version is 5.2.17 in the server.

Comment: It's only supported in 5.3+

Comment: @SuryaS [*PHP 5 >= 5.3.0*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php)

Comment: Haha +1. Would never catch this up

Comment: Yep, that'll be it. Namespaces are only valid from PHP v5.3 upward. (but note, if you're on v5.2, you should upgrade urgently because 5.2 hasn't been supported for several years now)